# front-end technology stack for e-commerce applications

Tags: android, ios, iphone

I am planning to develop an ecommerce application for web browsers and mobile platforms. I am a java developer. I will prefer java as a backend technology but I am not confident which technologies are best for front-end.
can anyone tell me which technologies are best suitable for front-end for below platforms:
1. browsers web application
2. android app
3. ios app

Answer (score 0):

First of all, AFAIK you should choose those technologies that will help you be more productive! 
According to me, native-fan, I suggest you use [PhoneGap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PhoneGap) (CSS, HTML5 + Javascript FRAMEWORK) for your purpose.

PhoneGap helps you to write one application which you will deploy for android ios or browser. You may also need to adjust your UI Features (such as width/height etc) to match a given device.